# Featured image metabox not showing for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

i am trying to add featured image for the custom post type

i have added the theme support in my theme's functions.php file. the following are the code:

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats',array('link','gallery'));
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background');
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header');
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo');
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links');
    // add_theme_support( 'html5');
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag');
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_theme_setup');
```

i also tried adding the support clause to the register post type section still nothing.

here is the register custom post type code:

```
function movies_create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'movies',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-video',
      'show_ui' => true,
    )
  );
}

add_action('init','movies_create_post_type');
```

i have searched everywhere but cant find a proper solution for this issue.

> Note: i can set set featured image for my normal post, issue is with
>   the custom post type. Also i have register custom post type through a
>   plugin which i coded myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try putting supports array outside two indexes just like public has_archive menu_icon show_ui

Comment: thanks a lot. that worked!!!

Comment: posted as answer to help others !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting supports array outside two indexes just like public has_archive menu_icon show_ui like

```
function movies_create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'movies',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-video',
      'show_ui' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

In support argument not pass in labels array

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
```

please check below code

```
function movies_create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'movies',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-video',
      'show_ui' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

for more info check [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)